# jest --watch throws Error: EACCES: permission denied for directory owned by root

Tags: docker, jestjs, permission-denied

#### Problem

When I run `jest --watch`, I get a permission denied error on a directory in my repository, even if I use `watchPathIgnorePatterns` for the directory:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/path/to/repo/.pgdata'
```

- `.pgdata/` is a directory used as a Docker volume for postgresql.
- The directory is owned by `root`.

#### Solutions tried

I tried using `watchPathIgnorePatterns` in my jest config:

```
watchPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/\\.pgdata/'],
```

I tried a similar pattern for `modulePathIgnorePatterns` and `testPathIgnorePatterns`.

I also tried setting the owner of `.pgdata` to my user with `chown`, but that required a change in the Docker setup that I don't want to make right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [roots](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#roots-arraystring) config property fixed the problem:

```
roots: ['<rootDir>/__tests__']
```

This tells jest to only search for files in the `__tests__` directory.

**Note**: I only have tests in `__tests__`, and I don't have a `src/` directory. If I did, it would probably have to be included as well, as shown in [the example in the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#roots-arraystring).

---

Even when using `watchPathIgnorePatterns`, the jest watcher still tries to run through all directories in the repository. Since it encounters a directory it does not have access to read from, it throws the error (tested on jest 28.1.0)

This unrelated [issue comment](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2789#issuecomment-520808767) for jest hinted at the solution.